# Вытянуть текст между символами и началом новой строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть следующий текст:

```
QR-Code:какой-то текст
QR-Code:еще какой-то текст
QR-Code:текст для кода
QR-Code:текст для кодирования
scanned 6 barcode symbols from 6 images
```

нужно вытянуть значения QR-кодов между "QR-Code:" и символом начала новой строки.

пробую регулярным выражением типа:

```
QR-Code:(.*)\n
```

не получается. подскажите как его правильно составить?

Comment: Разве слэш в /n не должен быть обратным? (Опечатка в самой пробуемой регулярке или только в данном вопросе?)

Comment: просто опечатка в вопросе. QR-Code:(.*)\n

Comment: У вас там многострочный текст? Перед каждым QR — перевод строки?

Comment: да. текст многострочный. перед каждым QR-Code новая строка

Comment: А язык какой? Укажите.

Answer (score 1):

Перловый скрипт

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $text = <<CUT;
QR-Code:какой-то текст
QR-Code:еще какой-то текст
QR-Code:текст для кода
QR-Code:текст для кодирования
scanned 6 barcode symbols from 6 images
CUT

my @codes = $text =~ /QR-Code:(.+?)\n/mg;

print join "\n", @codes;
```

выводит такой результат:

```
какой-то текст
еще какой-то текст
текст для кода
текст для кодирования
```

То, что надо?

Comment: my @codes = $text =~ /QR-Code:(.+?)$/mg;

тоже работает

Comment: http://ideone.com/YoJzGy :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну и для красоты) ... [на Руби](http://ideone.com/lxHVam):

```
str = <<EOT
QR-Code:какой-то текст
QR-Code:еще какой-то текст
QR-Code:текст для кода
QR-Code:текст для кодирования
scanned 6 barcode symbols from 6 images
EOT
puts str.scan(/QR-Code:(.*)\n/)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6

Куда же без него?)))

```js
var res = [];

`QR-Code:какой-то текст
QR-Code:еще какой-то текст
QR-Code:текст для кода
QR-Code:текст для кодирования
scanned 6 barcode symbols from 6 images`
.replace(/QR-Code:(.*)/gmi, (m, g) => res.push(g));

console.log(res);
```